# How to suppress quotes in the result of a built-in function?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, if I have  in `A1` the formula `=left(A2;5)`, with ABCDEFG in `A2`, the result is "ABCDE", and I would like ABCDE. Quotes are only visible when copy/pasting in a notepad.

EDIT : error of mine, I had " ABCDEFG " in `A2`

Comment: Do you need the quotes in column A? If not, then I would simply find/replace " with nothing.

Comment: Hmmm. I cannot reproduce your problem. When I select A2 and "copy"; then open a notepad document and "paste", quotes do not appear.

Comment: I'm unable to understand that how you are getting "ABCDE" in quotes,,, since in A1 you have simply ABCDEFG ,, and even if are in A1 within the quotes,, then also the `LEFT(A1,5)` could never return value in quotes,, [edit] your post & add the sample data along with the value of A1 in Formula bar,,, or upload the WB on cloud and let us examine !!

Comment: Please try to double click A1, press F9, then copy the result, press Esc and then copy to notepad to have a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `=left(CLEAN(TRIM(A2));5)`. I mistakened myself, I had quotes and spaces in `A2`